# How to make a line break in HTML with no spacing

Tags: html, css

Although using `<br>` obviously gives a line break, it also creates spacing between the lines. I am trying to have an image, below another image with no spacing. How can I make it that there is no line spacing at all; I guess using CSS?

Comment: Seriously, changing your question so significantly is not cool. You're asking a completely different question now. For latecomers: the original question was about line breaks in general. Now it's about images.

Comment: A bit late for everyone for you to finally expose correctly your worrie !

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use `<br>`, `<p>` or any other line breaking tag, use CSS styles such as margin, padding, and line-height to control line spacing.

Answer (score 1):

line-height property

```
line-height: 10px;
```

You can also specify value in % (100%, 30% etc.)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RWayz/. **You need to reset vertical-align on img tag**.

```
img {vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are having a problem with the default borwser style sheet, or perhaps even your own stylesheet.  `<br>` in and of itself does not provide spacing.  You might consider using a CSS reset in order to remove any default browser styles that give your undesired layout.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal just purely for UI? If so then use CSS only. If you actually need the semantics for structure, you can also try the `<HR>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this answers the original posted question. The question has since been changed to be about images.**

Use the paragraph tag and set margin to zero in the css.

HTML:

```
<p>Content.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{ margin: 0; }
```

See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/beThV/).

This will cause paragraphs to be created, and you can control any spacing between them using the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties. (In this example, there is no margin.)